# How to call factory/service from controller in AngularJS? error: Unknown Provider error in component $injector

Tags: angularjs

I'm developing a mobile app with AngularJS. First I called all $http requests inside a controller as I would usually do. Now that I've read more about Angular I've seen that that may not be the best practice, especially if you want to share data between controllers. So i'm now reinventing my controller/service system.

Now to the problem. I'm calling a service from the controller, but I'm getting an error: Unknown Provider error in component $injector

Could anyone help me?

The codez:

```
listdnModule.factory('getActiveDnService', function ($scope, $http) {
    return {
            getActiveDnSvc: function (id) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'POST', url: 'svc.aspx/getActiveDN', data: "{'id':" + id + "}", cache: true
                });
            }
    };
});

listdnModule.controller('listdnCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'getActiveDnService', function ($scope, $http, svc) {
    $scope.mjav = 1;
    svc.getActiveDnSvc($scope.mjav).success(function (data) {
        $scope.listdn = data.d;
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `$scope` from the injected dependencies of the service, `$scope` can only be injected to controllers, and passed in as parameters of link functions of directives in angular. Your service shoule look like:

```
listdnModule.factory('getActiveDnService', function ($http) {
    return {
            getActiveDnSvc: function (id) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'POST', url: 'svc.aspx/getActiveDN', data: "{'id':" + id, cache: true
                });
            }
    };
});
```

Comment: That is almost true. The scope in the link function are not injections, are just normal parameters. But your answer is correct.

Comment: You welcome. That is the reason you don't see `$scope` in the link but `scope`, more to say: "This is a normal parameter" :)

Comment: Oh thank you kind sir! I've been reading about not being able to do that, but I didn't think of it since it's all really new to me and I've been working for 2 days straight. You have saved me from alot of frustration. I thank you again!